# Checking if a set of vectors is basis for Rn when you have more than n vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble deciding how to deal with what should be an otherwise easy problem. Namely, I need to check whether

$${(1,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$$

would be considered a basis for $R^3$. It's trivial that the vectors are not, indeed, linearly independent, but if you remove any one vector from the set, you would get an LI set, and thus a basis for $R^3$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no basis with more vectors than the dimension of the space. A theorem says that any basis of a given vector space has the same number of vectors, which is then defined to be the dimension of that space.

Comment: Ok then, if that's the definition then you are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AS you say any three vectors of your set are linearly independent, so any three vectors can be taken as a basis. If you want an orthonormal basis than note the the last three vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ have norm $=1$ and are orthogonal (in the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^3$), so taking these three vectors we have an orthonormal basis.